# Sql count() for two parameters

Tags: sql, count, mariadb

How do I get count for two parameters for the following set:

```
beds : 2, classRate : 3
beds : 2, classRate : 3
beds : 4, classRate : 3
beds : 4, classRate : 3
beds : 4, classRate : 3
beds : 4, classRate : 3
beds : 4, classRate : 4
beds : 4, classRate : 4
beds : 4, classRate : 4
```

The result set should be:

```
beds : 2, classRate : 3, count :2
beds : 4, classRate : 3, count :4
beds : 4, classRate : 4, count :3
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose that you have Table1 with (beds, classrates) columns then,

```
select beds, classrates, count(*) from table1 
group by beds, classrates
```

would to what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CLASS_RATE, BEDS, COUNT(*) AS CC FROM ROOMS
WHERE (CLASS_RATE >= ? AND CLASS_RATE <= ?) GROUP BY CLASS_RATE, BEDS
```

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details

Answer (score -1):

select beds, classrates, count(*) from table1 group by beds, classrates

Try this. Count(*) will return counting of result.